# Newbie - Trouble with Install Freezing

Tags: installation, hard-drive, windows-xp

I recently booted up an old PC Tower of mine (like from 2003) because I wanted a PC to use for writing. It has XP on it, but it is stuffed to the gills with old programs and files, so much so that I thought it would be easiest to just start clean with Ubuntu.

I followed the directions for a bootable USB, and was able to get to the installation stage, but it always freezes when it comes to the screen that asks if I want to install over XP. The only thing I can do is cancel it, and then it says there was an unrecoverable internal error. I thought perhaps XP was just being a booger and tried to wipe it from the hard drive, but (Newbie) I was having trouble with that using the Command Prompt.

I guess my question is what should I do? Could my PC just be too old? Is the problem that I don't have internet connected when I'm trying to install? Is it XP?

Any suggestions would really help, because I'm stumped!

Thanks!

Edit: Trying to install 12.04

Comment: Check the disk SMART status with the disk utility, and open a terminal and run `dmesg` to see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

To validate that your hardware is supported, 
when booting on USB, at boot prompt, choose the desktop session ("Try Ubuntu without installing").

If you manage to finish the boot, open a file manager (the "home folder" icon in the left bar), you should see that your XP partitions are mounted (and could check your files). T

After that start the installer ("Install Ubuntu" icon on desktop).

If it fails you can :

- start a terminal and check for system messages with dmesg
- look at the /var/log/installer/debug file

(and check in the forums  for a solution)

If you note some message complaining about the disks, there is a "disk check" option at boot, that's worth to be tried.

Good luck

Emman